# Mass edit (create/destroy) many2many relation on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stucked in the way to do this task on Rails 5.

I need to "mass" edit a relation between a `Project` and it's `Members`

In the UI, I open a popup with a certain list of members (a list of `User`) and those member have or have not belongs to the `Project` (check the relations down here).

I need to have the ability to mark some of them (who not belongs to) or unmark others (who belongs to) with checkbox's and "save" the form and create/delete the relations.

For the record I have this models

```
// project.rb

class Project < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'ProjectMember'
     has_many :members, through: :memberships, class_name: 'User', source: :user
end


// project_member.rb

class ProjectMember < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :project
end

// user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many    :project_members
    has_many    :projects, through: :project_members
end
```

I'm kinda new on Rails and I'm really stucked in the way to create the forms (using SimpleForms) and how to edit the relation.

What's the correct approach? I tried to find over the web without success :(

I hope my question it's clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the helpers you want are included in the gem cocoon : https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Using this gem, your view for the project edition would look like this :

projects/_form

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  -# your project fields... 
  %h3 Members
  #members
    = f.simple_fields_for :members do |member|
      = render 'member_fields', f: member
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add member', f, :members
  = f.submit
```

projects/_member_fields

```
.nested-fields
  = f.association :user
  = link_to_remove_association "remove user from project", f
```

**Edit** : I focused on the view part, but before that, in the model, you have to accept nested attributes from forms :

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'ProjectMember'
  has_many :members, through: :memberships, class_name: 'User', source: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

There's also a bit of work to do in the controller to permit the nested attributes.

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, members_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: uhmm, but I need to have a entire list of users with checkboxs and a save button.

Comment: Hmm, that would be compatible with the above, if you add a boolean field is_member to the membership model. But you'd have to create the membershipos as soon as the project is saved, which is a bit convoluted